# How to improve custom Highlights Text Control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom control that uses a text block and highlights text based on properties on the control. When the control is used in a data grid the scrolling of the grid is slow. Based on the code of the control and specifically the OnRender method what can be done to make the control faster. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

**Update**
Sorry I had to delete the previous code which used a TextBlock, the edit was too long.

I have ditched using a TextBlock to provide the hilite support. Instead I am using FrameworkElement as the base class for the control, and drawing the text the OnRender method. This has greatly improved the scroll speed of the data grid. I am not sure if this is the best way to go any help you can provide will be appreciated.

**Namespaces**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
```

**Code**

```
    public class SearchableTextControl : FrameworkElement, IDisposable
{
    #region Constructors


    static SearchableTextControl ()
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata ( typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( typeof ( SearchableTextControl ) ) );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            LogProvider.Logger.LogException ( "Error during static SearchableTextControl()", ex );
            throw;
        }
    }


    public SearchableTextControl ()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid ();
    }

    ~SearchableTextControl ()
    {
        Dispose ( false );
    }


    #endregion


    #region Properties


    protected string DisplayText
    {
        get
        {
            var displayText = Text;

            // format if needed
            if ( DataFormatString != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty ( Text ) )
            {
                DateTime timeTmp;

                if ( DateTime.TryParse ( Text, out timeTmp ) )

                    displayText = timeTmp.ToString ( DataFormatString );
                else
                    displayText = string.Format ( DataFormatString, Text );
            }

            return displayText;
        }

    }


    public Guid Id
    { get; private set; }



    object _syncLock = new object ();
    public object SyncLock
    {
        get { return _syncLock; }
    }


    #endregion



    #region Dependency Properties

    public bool IsMatch
    {
        get {  return ( bool ) GetValue ( IsMatchProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue ( IsMatchProperty, value );
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMatchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "IsMatch", typeof ( bool ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( null ) );



    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            string text = null;

            var val = GetValue ( TextProperty );

            try
            {
                var valStr = val as string;
                if ( valStr != null )
                    text = valStr;
                else if ( val != null )
                    text = val.ToString ();
            }
            catch
            {
                text = null;
            }

            return text;
        }
        set { SetValue ( TextProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "Text", typeof ( string ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );


    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return ( FontFamily ) GetValue ( FontFamilyProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue ( FontFamilyProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "FontFamily", typeof ( FontFamily ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( new FontFamily ( "Segoe UI" ), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );


    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return ( FontStyle ) GetValue ( FontStyleProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue ( FontStyleProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "FontStyle", typeof ( FontStyle ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( FontStyles.Normal, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return ( FontWeight ) GetValue ( FontWeightProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue ( FontWeightProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "FontWeight", typeof ( FontWeight ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( FontWeights.Regular, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );

    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get { return ( FontStretch ) GetValue ( FontStretchProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue ( FontStretchProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "FontStretch", typeof ( FontStretch ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( FontStretches.Normal, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );

    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return ( double ) GetValue ( FontSizeProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue ( FontSizeProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "FontSize", typeof ( double ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( 12.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );



    public string DataFormatString
    {
        get { return ( string ) GetValue ( DataFormatStringProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( DataFormatStringProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataFormatStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "DataFormatString", typeof ( string ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );


    public Brush HiLiteBackground
    {
        get { return ( Brush ) GetValue ( HiLiteBackgroundProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( HiLiteBackgroundProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HiLiteBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "HiLiteBackground", typeof ( Brush ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new UIPropertyMetadata ( Brushes.Yellow ) );

    public Brush HiLiteForeground
    {
        get { return ( Brush ) GetValue ( HiLiteForegroundProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( HiLiteForegroundProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HiLiteForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "HiLiteForeground", typeof ( Brush ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new UIPropertyMetadata ( Brushes.Red ) );


    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return ( Brush ) GetValue ( BackgroundProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( BackgroundProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "Background", typeof ( Brush ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new UIPropertyMetadata ( Brushes.White ) );


    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return ( Brush ) GetValue ( ForegroundProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( ForegroundProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "Foreground", typeof ( Brush ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new UIPropertyMetadata ( Brushes.Black ) );

    public bool MatchCase
    {
        get { return ( bool ) GetValue ( MatchCaseProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( MatchCaseProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MatchCaseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "MatchCase", typeof ( bool ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );


    public bool MatchWholeWord
    {
        get { return ( bool ) GetValue ( MatchWholeWordProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( MatchWholeWordProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MatchWholeWordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "MatchWholeWord", typeof ( bool ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );


    public bool HiLiteEnabled
    {
        get { return ( bool ) GetValue ( HiLiteEnabledProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( HiLiteEnabledProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HiLiteEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "HiLiteEnabled", typeof ( bool ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );

    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return ( string ) GetValue ( SearchTextProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( SearchTextProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ( "SearchText", typeof ( string ), typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );





    #region HiLiteFontWeight

    public FontWeight HiLiteFontWeight
    {
        get { return ( FontWeight ) GetValue ( HiLiteFontWeightProperty ); }
        set { SetValue ( HiLiteFontWeightProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HiLiteFontWeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register (
            "HiLiteFontWeight",
            typeof ( FontWeight ),
            typeof ( SearchableTextControl ),
            new PropertyMetadata ( FontWeights.Normal ) );

    #endregion


    #endregion

    #region Overrides

    protected FormattedText FormattedText
    { get; set; }



    protected override Size ArrangeOverride ( Size finalSize )
    {
        var ft = GenerateFormattedText ( DisplayText, false );

        return new Size ( ft.Width, ft.Height );
    }


    protected override Size MeasureOverride ( Size availableSize )
    {
        var ft = GenerateFormattedText ( DisplayText, false );

        return new Size ( ft.Width, ft.Height );
    }

    protected override void OnRender ( DrawingContext dc )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( !IsVisible )
                return;

            dc.DrawRectangle ( Background, null, new Rect ( 0.0, 0.0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight ) );

            // if no text move on
            var text = DisplayText;
            if ( text == null )
                return;

            double x = 0;
            FormattedText ft = null;

            if ( !HiLiteEnabled || string.IsNullOrEmpty ( SearchText ) )
            {
                ft = GenerateFormattedText ( DisplayText, false );
                dc.DrawText ( ft, new Point ( x, 0 ) );
                return;
            }

            Trace ( "SearchableTextControl.Update Text: " + Text + " SearchText: " + SearchText + " HiLiteEnabled: " + HiLiteEnabled + " MatchCase: " + MatchCase );


            string searchText = null, compareText = null;


            if ( !MatchWholeWord )
            {
                searchText = MatchCase ? ( string ) SearchText : SearchText.ToLower ();
                compareText = MatchCase ? Text : Text.ToLower ();
            }
            else
            {
                searchText = SearchText;
                compareText = Text;
            }

            var displayText = text;

            int pos = -1;
            bool hilite = false;
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty ( searchText ) )
            {
                if ( !MatchWholeWord )
                {
                    int searchLength = searchText.Length;
                    while ( ( pos = compareText.IndexOf ( searchText ) ) >= 0 )
                    {

                        ft = GenerateFormattedText( displayText.Substring ( 0, pos ), false );

                        if ( ft != null )
                        {
                            dc.DrawText ( ft, new Point ( x, 0 ) );

                            x += ft.Width;
                        }

                        ft = GenerateFormattedText ( displayText.Substring ( pos, searchLength ), true );

                        if ( ft != null )
                        {
                            dc.DrawRectangle ( HiLiteBackground, null, new Rect ( x, 0, ft.Width, ft.Height ) );
                            dc.DrawText ( ft, new Point ( x, 0 ) );

                            x += ft.Width;
                        }

                        compareText = compareText.Substring ( pos + searchLength );
                        displayText = displayText.Substring ( pos + searchLength );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( searchText == compareText )
                        hilite = true;
                }

                ft = GenerateFormattedText ( displayText, hilite );
                if ( ft != null )
                    dc.DrawText ( ft, new Point ( x, 0 ) );

            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            LogProvider.Logger.LogException ( "Error during searchable text control onrender", ex );
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers


    #endregion

    #region Support Methods

    public virtual void Release ()
    {

    }


    private FormattedText GenerateFormattedText ( string text, bool isHiLite )
    {
        var background = isHiLite ? HiLiteBackground : Background;
        var foreground = isHiLite ? HiLiteForeground : Foreground;

        // Set the source text with the style which is Italic.
        var fontStyle = isHiLite ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal;

        // Set the source text with the style which is Bold.
        var fontWeight = isHiLite ? HiLiteFontWeight : FontWeights.Normal;


        var typeface = new Typeface ( FontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, FontStretch );



        // Create formatted text--in a particular font at a particular size
        var ft = new FormattedText (
            text,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface,
            FontSize,
            foreground );

        ft.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;

        return ft;
    }


    private void Trace ( string msg )
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine( msg );
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable

    public bool IsDisposed
    { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose ()
    {
        Dispose ( true );

        GC.SuppressFinalize ( this );
    }


    private void Dispose ( bool disposing )
    {
        if ( IsDisposed || !disposing )
            return;

        lock ( SyncLock )
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
            Release ();

        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: The easiest way is use RichTextBox. There are a lot of code sample in internet. You may don't believe, but to find and hightlight text, RichTextBox peformance is much much better than TextBlock (I have tested myself before). You can allow user edit if you want. The fastest method is managed DirectWrite, but it is a bit difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The lightweight element using DrawText I saw in on stackoverflow and gave it a try.It provides excellent performance in the data grid.